# How do I rewrite this MySQL query to use less memory?

Tags: mysql

I was practicing writing mysql queries with a sample mysql database that has 500k entries in employees and and salaries (see tables below). I wanted a list of managers who are not in finance but make more money than at least one person in finance. (dept_no=`d002`)

query:

```
SELECT salaries.salary, employees.first_name, employees.last_name 
FROM salaries, employees, dept_manager, dept_emp
WHERE employees.emp_no=dept_manager.emp_no
AND dept_manager.dept_no <> "d002"
AND salaries.emp_no = dept_manager.emp_no
AND salaries.salary > ANY 
    (SELECT salary FROM salaries, dept_emp 
        WHERE dept_emp.dept_no="d002" 
        AND salaries.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no);
```

This query crashes the sql server because it runs out of memory before it can complete. This is on a macbook 10.6 2.2GB core duo and 2Gb RAM. Granted this may be asking a lot but I feel like there should be a way of doing this with somewhat limited computing power. I've done other queries without crashing (they were pretty slow but still)

error message for the curious:

```
mysql(611) malloc: *** mmap(size=3870720) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
mysql: Out of memory (Needed 3869736 bytes)
ERROR 2008 (HY000): MySQL client ran out of memory
```

table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
    UNIQUE  KEY (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_manager (
   dept_no      CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
   emp_no       INT             NOT NULL,
   from_date    DATE            NOT NULL,
   to_date      DATE            NOT NULL,
   KEY         (emp_no),
   KEY         (dept_no),
   FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees (emp_no)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
); 

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    KEY         (emp_no),
    KEY         (dept_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);

CREATE TABLE titles (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    title       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE,
    KEY         (emp_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,title, from_date)
); 

CREATE TABLE salaries (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    salary      INT             NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    KEY         (emp_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date)
);
```

No I didn't write this it was available from a third party site linked from the MySQL website.

Comment: Where's your `WHERE` clause for the `dept_emp` table?

Comment: @MarcusAdams That'd do it...

Comment: @Marcus: Oops. I ended up not needing that table. And it worked after I removed it. Can you post that as the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think you can also limit the subquery by selecting `MIN(salary) AS salary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely getting a `CROSS JOIN` aka *Cartesian product* because you are missing a `WHERE` clause for your join on the `dept_emp` table.